# Qtcharts does not render data

Tags: c++, qt, charts

I am trying to render 2 charts, that are basically the same, except for the Y data. This is the code

```
QtCharts::QLineSeries *cpuSeries = new QtCharts::QLineSeries();
        QtCharts::QLineSeries *ramSeries = new QtCharts::QLineSeries();

        QString string;
        while((string = in.readLine()) != nullptr){
            QStringList values = string.split(QLatin1Char(';'));
            QDateTime moment = QDateTime::fromString(values[0], "yyyy:MM:dd:hh:mm:ss");

            cpuSeries -> append(moment.toMSecsSinceEpoch(), values[2].toDouble());
            ramSeries -> append(moment.toMSecsSinceEpoch(), values[3].toDouble());

        }

        fileIO.close();
        QtCharts::QChart *cpuChart = new QtCharts::QChart();
        QtCharts::QChart *ramChart = new QtCharts::QChart();
        cpuChart -> addSeries(cpuSeries);
        ramChart -> addSeries(ramSeries);
        cpuChart -> legend() -> hide();
        ramChart -> legend() -> hide();
        cpuChart -> setTitle("Cpu usage over time");
        ramChart -> setTitle("Ram usage over time");


        QtCharts::QDateTimeAxis *cpuaxisX = new QtCharts::QDateTimeAxis;
        cpuaxisX->setTickCount(10);
        cpuaxisX->setFormat("dd-MM hh:mm");
        cpuaxisX->setTitleText("Date");

        QtCharts::QDateTimeAxis *ramaxisX = new QtCharts::QDateTimeAxis;
        ramaxisX->setTickCount(10);
        ramaxisX->setFormat("dd-MM hh:mm");
        ramaxisX->setTitleText("Date");


        cpuChart -> addAxis(cpuaxisX, Qt::AlignBottom);
        cpuSeries -> attachAxis(cpuaxisX);

        ramChart -> addAxis(ramaxisX, Qt::AlignBottom);
        ramSeries ->attachAxis(ramaxisX);

        QtCharts::QValueAxis *cpuaxisY = new QtCharts::QValueAxis;
        cpuaxisY->setLabelFormat("%f");
        cpuaxisY->setTitleText("Percentage");

        QtCharts::QValueAxis *ramaxisY = new QtCharts::QValueAxis;
        ramaxisY->setLabelFormat("%f");
        ramaxisY->setTitleText("Mb");



        cpuChart->addAxis(cpuaxisY, Qt::AlignLeft);
        cpuSeries->attachAxis(cpuaxisY);
        ramChart->addAxis(ramaxisY, Qt::AlignLeft);
        ramSeries->attachAxis(ramaxisY);


        QtCharts::QChartView *cpuChartView = new QtCharts::QChartView(cpuChart);
        QtCharts::QChartView *ramChartView = new QtCharts::QChartView(ramChart);
        cpuChartView -> setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        ramChartView -> setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);


        QGridLayout *cpuGrid  = ui -> centralwidget -> findChild<QGridLayout *>("cpuGrid");
        QGridLayout *ramGrid = ui -> centralwidget -> findChild<QGridLayout *>("ramGrid");


        cpuGrid -> addWidget(cpuChartView);
        ramGrid -> addWidget(ramChartView);
```

As you can see, both charts are created using the exact same code, except for the data and titles. However, this is the result

[image]

I have printed values[3], and it is correct.
Also, if I pass it the values[2] data, it works, and both charts look exactly the same.
The values[3] values are over 10000, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, but it's very weird... The problem was the data was all exactly the same, and apparently, if all the data is the same it doesn't render anything... I'm guessing it's because it calculates the range as being 0, and then it can't show anything...

Edit: In fact, if I manually set the range of the graph, it shows the data just fine.